# How to execute mysql code with semicolon in php?

Tags: php, mysql, parsing

The code is

```
INSERT INTO `semicolon` VALUES ('1', 'a:1:{s:4:\"size\"';\s:2:\"24\";\}');
```

As you might see in double single quotes there is `;` (semicolon) and it splits the code because it's the execution sign.

I get an syntax error message otherwise without `;` (semicolon) it works fine. If use software like phpmyadmin or navicat it works even with the semicolon.

The question is how to fix it to run within PHP file?

Comment: why are you not using mysql_real_escape_string() and why are you inserting a serialised array against normalisation?

Comment: and why is your table name semicolon... ?

Comment: @Dagon because every friggin answer on this site says to use mysql_real_escape_string() to "protect user data from scaring SQL injection". So, when there is no user data or no danger, no one minds this function ever.

Comment: looks like user data to me, from a form i would bet on

Comment: this is to fill sample data during installation of the script it runs only once nobody can run it. the table named semicolon you to be able test it on the fly.

Comment: serilasied array in db is almost always wrong.

Answer (score 8):

It is due to your single quote, not your semicolon:

```
INSERT INTO semicolon VALUES ('1', 'a:1:{s:4:\"size\"';\s:2:\"24\";}'); 
-----------------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: @JackWill post your PHP code then, you only gave us a mysql insert

Answer (score 6):

Actually `'` is splitting the code. Escape it with `\'`

```
 INSERT INTO semicolon VALUES ('1', 'a:1:{s:4:\"size\"\';\s:2:\"24\";}');
```

`'` is a string delimiter in SQL. The SQL engine things the string ends with the `'`.

Comment: It doesn't work: ...for the right syntax to use near ''a:1:  {s:4:\"size\"\'' at line 1
Statement:
INSERT INTO `semicolon` VALUES ('1', 'a:1:{s:4:\"size\"\'  - this is stopping at ; - semicolon, if get rid of it it "will work". Other ideas?